# Spring Boot cannot autowired component with abstract and interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, autowired

In my Spring Boot 2.0.2 application I am trying to inject a component herited from abstract class which implements an interface and it doesn't work.

Code :

**Component Abstract :** (Do I need to put @Component ?)

```
package app.project.service;

@Component
public abstract class AbstractStepService implements IStepService {

    protected final void addTask() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public StepDataDto launch() throws StepException {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Interface :**

```
package app.project.service;

public interface IStepService  {
    StepDataDto launch() throws StepException;
}

package app.project.service;
```

**Component :**

```
@Component
public class CStepServiceImpl extends AbstractStepService implements IStepService {

    @PostConstruct
    private void defineTasks() {
    }
}

package app.project.service;
```

**Junit Test :**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CStepServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("cStepServiceImpl")
    private IStepService service;

}

package app.project;
```

**Application :**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages ={"app.project.service"})
public class MyApplication {}
```

**Error message when launching my Junit test :**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'app.project.service.IStepService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=cStepServiceImpl)}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your declaration like this

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("CStepServiceImpl")
private IStepService service;
```

or

```
@Autowired
private IStepService CStepServiceImpl;
```

That should work. The bean name created automatically by spring has CStepServiceImpl name.

You can also name your bean like this

```
@Component(value = "myName")
public class CStepServiceImpl extends AbstractStepService implements IStepService {

}
```

and use myName during Autowiring.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I though that qualifier's name needs to begin with a lower case character ... I will also add: abstract classes don't need to be annotated with `@Component` (cannot be instanciated).

Comment: Yes. abstract classes don't need to have `@Component`. In most of the cases bean names generated will follow camelcase naming structure. But in certain cases like yours(you have two uppercase letters in the beginning of class name), the names generated are different. If you name your class CstepServiceImpl, then it will generate bean name as cstepServiceImpl.